# CSS/HTML/PHP CSS not being applied to HTML

Tags: php, html, css

I'm not very good at website developing but as this is my graded unit and im trying to make it nice.

Im running into an issue with HTML and CSS (possibly PHP as well?) where it is not being applied when im using classes.

Things ive tried so far:
Put the CSS through w3schools error checks - Clean
Directly linking the CSS in the admin.php instead of through the seperate header - No effect
Directly applying the css is style tags (Tried inputting 'style"color:white;"' into both the thead and table tags) - No effect
I am using bottstrap for easier styling so maybe this is overpowering the CSS? My stylesheet is being called after though so this "shouldn't" be the case.

admin.php (the file i want the css to be applied to):

```
<?php
require 'header.php';
?>
 <br><br><br>

    <table class="aT">
    <thead class="aTH">
        <td>Member Number</td>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td>Forename(s)</td>
        <td>Surname</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Date Of Birth</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>User Type (1 = admin, 2 = Verified Seller, 3 = Unverified Seller)</td>
        <td>Phone number</td>
    </thead>
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT userid, username, forenames, surname, email, dob, age, usergroup, phonenumber FROM members");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="memberno" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['userid']?></td>
            <td id="username" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['username']?></td>
            <td id="dob" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['forenames']?></td>
            <td id="salutation" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['surname']?></td>
            <td id="forenames" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['email']?></td>
            <td id="surname" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $row['dob']?></td>
            <td id="email" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $row['age']?></td>
            <td id="user_type" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['usergroup']?></td>
            <td id="user_type" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $row['phonenumber']?></td>
        </tr>

    <?php
    }
?>
</tbody>

<?php
include 'footer.php';
?>
```

header.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<?php
require 'mysqli.php';
?>
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Ross's Rides</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="buysell.php">Buy/Sell</a></li>
        </ul>
        <?php
          if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
            { 
                session_start(); 
            } 
          if (!isset($_SESSION["admin"]) && !isset($_SESSION["user"]) && !isset($_SESSION["useru"])) {
              ?>
            <form method="get" action="login.php" class="btn_1">
            <a class="btn btn_2 navbar-btn" href="login.php">Login/Register</a>
            </form>
            <?php 
          }
          else {
              ?>
            <form method="get" action="logout.php" class="btn_1">
            <a class="btn btn_2 navbar-btn" href="logout.php">Logout</a>
            </form> 
            <?php
          }
          if (isset($_SESSION["admin"])) {
              ?>
            <form method="get" action="admin.php" class="btn_1">
            <a class="btn btn_2 navbar-btn" href="admin.php">Admin Panel</a>
            </form>
            <?php
          }
        ?>
      </div>
    </nav>
</head>
```

stylesheet.css:

```
.btn_1 {
    display:inline;
    float: right;
}

.btn_2 {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    color: white;
}

.loginBox {
    padding-top: 100px;
}

.submitBtn {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    color: white;
}

.cancelBtn {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    color: white;
}

.registerForm {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.redText {
    color: red;
}

.aT {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px;
    border: thick;
    border-color: limegreen;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;   
}

.aTH {
    height: 50px;
}
```

Now I am almost certain a lot of my code is not "perfect" or following "proper procedures" and if you see any of this feel free to point it out and correct me as ive said im not that good at websites and could definetly learn a thing or two. I will be removing the 
 tags later when i can get the CSS to properly apply, until then they will stay as my sketchy fix for now.

Cheers for all the help, here is an image to show the effect of my attempts.
if you need any more info/pics/other stuff feel free to ask and ill try to get as much as possible up. the footer.php does contain an  if thats any consolation so the document does have an end!

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Seems like your styles are applying. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MmbvOe

Comment: Have you checked you document inspector or console log to see if there are errors reported

Comment: On my code view the styles are not applying, so this must be a clientside error, any idea on what this could be, i see the style being applied there but when im running the website from the files (Which have been saved) the styling doesnt show up? As for the document inspector or console log i dont really know how to use this on Dreamweaver?

Answer (score 1):

> On my code view the styles are not applying

Have you verified that all cache's have been cleared? I had this issue and I was struggling for quite awhile before I realized that my host cached the files automatically, as well as cloudflare cached it, AND Chrome cached it.

Comment: Tried clearing the cache and that hasnt helped at all, though ill admit I thought it for sure was the issue there as i ahdnt thought of that before at all.

Comment: The CSS does apply in firefox though, I think it must be somethign to do with chrome so ill keep working in firefox for now, cheers for the help!